# Search elements object with specific key value in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to search with specific value with of userkey in firebase database but i am getting below issues.

I want to fetch like if i pass user key 11112 then two records will come when i pass 11113 then one record will come.

[image]

Even though I have tried with below code but getting error.
firebase script :-

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.15/firebase.js'></script>
```

Code:

```
var ref = new Firebase('fire-base-url');
ref.orderBy("userkey").equalTo("11112").once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

Console Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ref.orderBy is not a function
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is two problems with your code.

1. As @theblindprophet already mentioned, you should be using `orderByChild` instead of `orderBy`.
2. You are using the old firebase SDK. It won't work with applications created in the [new firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

   Please make sure to use the new 3.1 firebase sdk with

   ```
   <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js'></script>
   ```

   Then you should initialize your app using

   ```
     var config = {
       apiKey: "",
       authDomain: "",
       databaseURL: "",
       storageBucket: "",
     };
     firebase.initializeApp(config);
   ```

   You will be able to get your config details by going to the console, clicking in your application name and pressing `Add Firebase to your Web app`.

   Then to get your `ref` object you will need the code bellow.

   `var ref = firebase.database().ref();`

Take a look in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/92/) to see a full working example.

Comment: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "author" at /Users to your security rules for better performance 
getting warning in jsfiddle

Comment: @bhaskarbhatt as the warning message says. you will be able to fix it by adding  `".indexOn": "author"` in your database rules (console -> database -> rules). I've just added it in my application and you wont see it again in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Your error:

> Uncaught TypeError: ref.orderBy is not a function

is telling it can't find the function `orderBy` and that is because it doesn't exist.

You are looking for `orderByChild`.

```
var ref = new Firebase('fire-base-url');
ref.orderByChild("userkey").equalTo("11112").once("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

Reference: [orderByChild and equalTo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo)

Comment: I got error message at console "Uncaught TypeError: ref.orderByChild is not a function"
I am using above mentioned firebase.js.
Is it preventing ?

Comment: You are using a very old version. Try `<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>`

Comment: And make you use this format: `https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/` inside `new Firebase`

Comment: Do you know why I'm getting ```Uncaught Error: Query.equalTo failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'incidents'```?

Answer (score 0):

Grab a snapshot of the uid values.  Then compare userkey with the search parameter you pass in.

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('fire-base-url');
var userRef = rootRef.child(user.uid);
userRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
  var myDbKey = snapshot.child("userkey");
  if (mySearchKey === myDbKey) {
    ...
  }
});
```