# Getting Username from Firebase after email/password login [React Native]

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have created a simple login app using react native that let's users signup, login, and logout. my signup function takes a username that is then used in the `createUser` callback to generate a db entry with the uid as the key, and the username entered as a value. The answer in this post is the structure I followed - [How do you include a username when storing email and password using Firebase (BaaS) in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151178/how-do-you-include-a-username-when-storing-email-and-password-using-firebase-ba)

After the user is logged in, I'd like to get the username and display it but I'm having trouble figuring this out.

This is the code I currently have to attempt and do it:

```js
var ref = new Firebase("https://myreactapp.firebaseio.com");

module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    var authData = ref.getAuth();
    var user = ref.child("users/" + authData.uid + "/username");
    return {
      username: user
    };
  },
```

This is how the code looks when I signup and the structure of my db.

```js
var self = this;
    let ref = new Firebase("https://myreactapp.firebaseio.com");
    ref.createUser({
      email    : this.state.email,
      password : this.state.password
    }, function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        return this.setState({errorMessage: 'Error creating user'});
      } else {
        ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
          username: self.state.username
         });
        console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", authData.uid);
        ToastAndroid.show('Account Created', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
        return self.props.navigator.pop();

      }
    });

----------------Not actual code-------------------------------------------------
DB

+users
--<uid>
  -username -> value
--<uid>
  -username -> value
```

I try to login and get an error of `maximum call stack exceeded`, but I have a feeling I'm going at this the wrong way. I've looked online, but everything I found was for retrieving data that is either being added, changed or deleted. All I want is to get this username once.

Comment: have you already stored the user data inside `/user/userId/`?

Comment: I'll edit my question to include how the data looks inside the db, but to answer your questions, I do have it there.

Comment: So the only problem I see here is that you are initializing your firebase app in the "legacy way". Please, take a look in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590303/search-elements-object-with-specific-key-value-in-firebase-database/38590740#38590740) to get more information on how you should be initializing it.

Comment: `maximum call stack exceeded` means you have an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: @EladKarni Stack Overflow is a bad medium to interactively debug. Can you set up a **minimal** jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the problem and link that into your question?

Comment: I apologize if my question wasn't clear enough. The error doesn't seem that important as I have a feeling the way I'm going about the issue is the problem. So my question is what's the correct way of getting data from a firebase dB. I'm using the "legacy way" because that's what I learned and it has the functionality I'm looking for.